# Stop flickering for border CSS animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm animating a section tag with a scale transform, I notice that when the animation is executing there is some flickering on the top and bottom border. Is there a way to stop such behavior? I already tried adding `transform-style: preserve-3d;` and `backface-visibility: hidden;` with no success, I made a Codepen replicating my problem

Thanks!

```css
body {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: linear-gradient( 0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(18, 18, 18, 1) 15%, rgba(55, 55, 55, 1) 100%);
  height: 100vh;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 500px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  animation: show-section 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes show-section {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

article {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #f2f2f2;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <h2>Text 1</h2>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Text 2</h2>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Text 3</h2>
  </article>
</section>
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/ddanielcruzz/pen/KKpMJMv)

Comment: Are you using Edge or Chrome? I also encountered this problem on Microsoft edge, because your codepen example runs fine on chrome.

Comment: The issue is more visible without the opacity and a minor speed. [Test it here](https://codepen.io/SnakeDrak/pen/RwPRvxW)

Comment: @prakharlondhe I'm using Chrome, as SnakeDrak mentioned, the issue is more visible in his example